# Run a webgl function in a three.js program

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

In my three.js script I want to use this webgl function : gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE,gl.ONE).
How can I do that with three.js ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var gl = renderer.context;
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE,gl.ONE);
```